# Armored Glass vs. Ballistic Glass

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

I'm confused about the difference between the two. How is armored glass different? It certainly has a higher structure and armor rating than ballistic glass. When would my players tend to encounter one over the other? Does a Stuffer Shack have ballistic glass over the doors? Armored glass? What about the windows in a car?

Comment: does the edition matter with this question? If so, can you please tag it with the appropriate tag

Comment: It's 5th edition. I updated the tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Armoured Glass v Ballistic Glass

The authors of Shadowrun have in this case used two common names for **[bulletproof glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletproof_glass)** to denote two different qualities or grades of the glass.

It is safe to assume that the Ballistic Glass in game is cheaper than the Armoured Glass, and that in this case the el cheap-o stuffer shack outlet would have the cheaper Ballistic Glass (and probably a low grade at that) and that the quality of the glass in the armoured limousine would depend on the limousine - for cheaper alternatives for hire or used by low-ranking execs, ballistic glass.  For higher execs, definitely armoured glass, or even higher, more theoretical levels of glass technology with higher ratings than listed in the book.

Regular cars would likely only have regular glass in the windows, albeit probably safety-glass.  Only luxury models would likely have bulletproof glass in their frames, the grade of which determined by 'how luxury, exactly' the model is.

Comment: as someone more knowledgeable with the setting, does this vary much between editions? The question has been updated to be specific to 5e, so you *might* need to tweak this depending...